# Install Xcode 4.2 on OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, xcode

Is there a way to install Xcode 4.2 on OS X 10.8?

I need to compile some Firemonkey projects on my MBP (latest without retina) and I have OS X 10.8 installed and through normal means it's not possible to install Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Which are those *normal means*?

Comment: Why can't you use the more modern Xcode 4.6 ?

Comment: If the reason is that you need the 10.6 SDK take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989007/where-to-get-sdk-10-6-for-xcode

Comment: 1- without destroying my current setup, preferable legal since I actually "own" a "license" for both osx 10.7 and 10.8
2-firemonkey only works with 4.2, I have the 4.6
3-no, that's not the reason.

Comment: Is Firemonkey this [dev environment](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/firemonkey/info)? If so what exactly does it need?

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, I added an answer explaining why Xcode 4.2 can't be installed on OS X 10.8. Now that your issue is solved (http://superuser.com/questions/562238/on-a-mac-that-was-originally-shipped-with-lion-how-can-i-replace-mountain-lion), could you take a look at my answer below and if you feel it answers your question mark your question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **you can't run Xcode 4.2 on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion).**

Xcode 4.2 is available as a download from the developer site at Apple:

[image]

but it needs Lion.

On Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.2.x will show an error message similar to this, as mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4148882?start=0&tstart=0) or [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Aug/msg00120.html):

```
This installation of Xcode 4.2.x requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.
```

If you need Xcode 4.2 you will need to install Lion, preferably on an external harddrive to avoid overwriting your current Mountain Lion installation.

Comment: yes, but **how** did you get those results?

Comment: @Thufir Honestly, I don't remember, my post is 2 years old. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

There's answer on [Apple discussions groups](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4268734?start=0&tstart=0) to install Mac OS X Lion into virtual machine to use previous FM-ios.

PS: You're allowed to install Mac OS X in virtual machine on Apple hardware which meets requirements.

Comment: As a side note: According to Apple's licensing policies, only OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) client or server, 10.7 (Lion) client or server, 10.6 (Snow Leopard) server and 10.5 (Leopard) server can be virtualized (see http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000131). Fortunately, the OP needs Lion, which can be virtualized in its client and server versions. There's a related question, also asked by the OP, here: http://superuser.com/questions/562238/recover-osx-lion-install/562268